# connect to more than 1 oracle database

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

I have written my code in a batchscript but I'm not getting the intended result. Below is my code:

```
echo updating database

cd C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\myfolder\web

sqlplus web/dbpassword @ web.sql > weblog.log

cd C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\myfolder\archive

sqlplus archive/dbpassword @ archive.sql > archive.log 

echo done
cmd /k
```

What I'm trying to do is connect to the **web** and execute **web.sql**, then connect to the **archive** and execute the **archive.sql**, but when I execute i see only **web logs** in **web** folder but not in **archive** folder, so only **web.sql** is executed and the **echo done** is never reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlplus continues to read commands from standard input to prevent this in scripts standard input can be closed

```
sqlplus web/dbpassword @ web.sql > weblog.log < NUL
```

Otherwise it may be called

```
sqlplus web/dbpassword < web.sql > weblog.log
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it is working  but one more thing, when I add set /p password= and then I use %password% instead of dbpassword it is stuck on 
echo updating database, it looks like it is not getting the password from input. Any clue?